# How do enable Alt-F2 to switch consoles?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gentoo

I recently installed gentoo on a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 laptop.  I have it dual booting windows and gentoo.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to switch virtual consoles using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>.  It seems to generate the escape sequence <kbd>^[[26~</kbd> instead of switching consoles.

My `/etc/inittab` has agetty instances for c1-c6, so the consoles should exist.

When I attach an external (USB) keyboard, the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> works from that external keyboard but the built-in keyboard still generates the escape sequence.

How do I fix it so that it works like every linux computer I have owned since 1992?  Did I forget to enable an option in the kernel?  Is there a gentoo config file I missed?

Comment: Unless Gentoo does it differently than I'm used to, you use `Ctrl` `Alt` `F1`, `Ctrl` `Alt` `F2` etc. to switch virtual controles, not just `Alt` alone.

Comment: No.  That is a common misconception among people who rarely use the text console and spend most of their time in X windows.  X windows requires Ctrl.  The text console does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my Dell laptop has a BIOS option on the `Advanced` tab titled `Function Key Behavior` that defaults to `Multimedia Key`.  Switching it to `Function Key` causes the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> to behave correctly.